# javascript: value of "this" inside of a function called by a method

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm attempting to use the keyword `this` inside of a function which is called by a method of an object. In the scope of the method, the value of `this` is the object. However, in the scope of the function called by that method, the value of `this` is not the object.

I've figured out that if I pass `this` as a parameter, the function works. The function does not work when `this` is used literally.

I know that the value of `this` inside of a method is the method's object. What rule determines the value of `this` in the scope of a function called by that method? Is it the value of `this` at the time/scope the function is defined (rather than at the time/scope that it is called)?

Erroneous code:

```
var setHeightTop = function(h,t){
  var prevWellHeight = $(this).parent().prev().height();
  $(this).css({
    "height": function() {return (prevWellHeight - h);},
    "top": function() {return -(prevWellHeight - t);} 
  }); 
};

var recalcConnectorLines = function() {
  $(".well + .well > .connectLine").each(function() {
    setHeightTop(1,28);
  });
};
```

Functioning code:

```
var setHeightTop = function(obj,h,t){
  var prevWellHeight = $(obj).parent().prev().height();
  $(obj).css({
    "height": function() {return (prevWellHeight - h);},
    "top": function() {return -(prevWellHeight - t);} 
  }); 
};

var recalcConnectorLines = function() {
  $(".well + .well > .connectLine").each(function() {
    setHeightTop(this,1,28);
  });
```

---

EDIT: SOLUTION.

Based on Mentok's link, I've figured out two things:

1. The value of `this` in a function is set at the time the function is
   defined. This explains the behavior I was seeing in my erroneous
   code.
2. However, if I invoked my function as a method, `this` would be defined at the
   time the method was called.

As explained [here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) in the jQuery documentation, it is possible to add new methods to the jQuery object.

My improved DRY code is:

```
$.fn.setHeightTop = function(h,t) {
  $(this).each(function() {
    var prevWellHeight = $(this).parent().prev().height();
    $(this).css({
      "height": function() {return (prevWellHeight - h);},
      "top": function() {return -(prevWellHeight - t);} 
    }); 
  });

};

var recalcConnectorLines = function() {
  $(".well + .well > .connectLine").setHeightTop(1,28);
};
```

It works!

Comment: Check [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) out (pun intended)

Comment: this takes the value of an object when the fucntion is called as a method of that object, you're getting this right, but the only way this happens is by calling the method as a property of the object with the notation object.method or object["method"]. In your example the value of this is defined by jQuery

Comment: @Mentok: That helps! However, it implies that I would need to set a variable equal to the function each time I want to use the function. I'm planning to use this function on a number of objects. Is there a way to reduce redundancy? Would I define the function as a method of all jQuery objects?

Comment: `var fnc = setHeightTop.bind(this); fnc(1,28);`

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the existing setHeightTop(obj,h,t)

```
.each(function(el,idx) {
    setHeightTop(el,1,28);
})
```

setHeight(h,t) has no context for a "this" object. The existing function should work fine.

Comment: I suppose there is nothing wrong with it, per se. I now understand why `setHeight(h,t)` doesn't work. It just seems repetitive to write `this` as the first parameter each time I call the function. I'm still trying to figure out if there is a more elegant solution.